# How to migrate mysql from localhost to IP address

Tags: mysql, host

I am running mysql in my localhost under the port number 3306. I want to access mysql database remotely. my system has the ip address and i want to use this instead of localhost. Can you please tell me how can i achieve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you written some code for it for accessing remote database.
Is there any error??
If you need to access your database remotely then you need to do following
.

Mysql :-

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 

 mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will grant to all users to access database remotely.

Comment: select current_user() gives root@localhost, but i want to change it like root@192.168.68.5

Comment: even if this command written in localhost remotely you can access by ip address also.so you no need to write ip address

Comment: I wonder, how it is happening? localhost is accessible to all the remote hosts, but i have given jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306 in my logic.

Comment: You have given the access to remote machine it is not related to localhost it is rights.